# Checkbox on column headercell of datagridview not able to align

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview control which contain some columns named Begin,End,OpenGl,OpenAP in the column header cell.

We are displaying text named Begin ,End on Column header cell  but for OpenGL and OpenAP we are dipalying checkbox not any text.I have done some following code but it is not working.

```
 objCheckBoxHeaderforOpenGL = new CustomControls.M3CheckBoxColumnHeader();
        objCheckBoxHeaderforOpenAP = new CustomControls.M3CheckBoxColumnHeader();            

        dgvFiscalPeriods.Columns["gcOpenGL"].HeaderCell = objCheckBoxHeaderforOpenGL;
        dgvFiscalPeriods.Columns["gcOpenAP"].HeaderCell = objCheckBoxHeaderforOpenAP;

        this.dgvFiscalPeriods.Columns["gcOpenGL"].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopCenter;
        this.dgvFiscalPeriods.Columns["gcOpenAP"].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopCenter;
```

and it is working fine with this following code

```
this.dgvFiscalPeriods.Columns["gcBegin"].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopCenter;
            this.dgvFiscalPeriods.Columns["gcEnd"].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopCenter;
```

How can i align any user control in datagrid view?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
 DGV.Columns["MyColumnName"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopCenter;
```

Comment: this for Grid cell only not header cell on datagridview.

Comment: Actually i have added a custom control to header cell in DataGridView but i am not able to set alignment of this header cell.